# Non-homogenous Difference Equation with $f(n) = 2^n$

Tags: recurrence-relations

I'm struggling to solve $$y_n + 5y_{n-1} - 14y_{n-2} = 2^n$$

I've solved the first part:
$${y_n}^{(h)} = A(-7)^n + B(2)^n$$

But struggling solving the particular solution.

I tried:

$${y_n}^{(p)} = Mk^n$$

$$Mk^n + 5(Mk^{n-1}) -14(Mk^{n-2}) = 2^n$$
$$\iff k^n(M+5Mk^{-1}-14Mk^{-2}) = 2 ^n$$
$$k = 2$$
$$M + \frac{5M}{2} - \frac{14M}{4} = 1 \iff 0 \ne 1$$
Next I tried with:
$${y_n}^{(p)} = Mk^n \cdot n$$
$$Mk^n \cdot n + 5Mk^{n-1}(n - 1) - 14Mk^{n-2}(n-2) = 2^n$$
$$k^n(Mn + 5Mnk^{-1}-5Mk^{-1} -14Mnk^{-2} + 28Mk^{-2}) = 2^n$$
I don't know how to proceed from here. Can you help?

Comment: Take $k=2$ and equate the coefficient of $n$ and constant term on RHS and LHS.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri how should I group in terms of $M$ and $n$? (How to group the M's and n's?

Comment: $M$ is a constant, so collect all the terms containing $n$. Since the coefficient of $n$ is zero on the RHS, it should be the same for the LHS. You should get$$(M+5M/k-14M/k^2)n+(28M/k^2-5M/k)=(2/k)^n$$Now see if $k=2$ works

Comment: @ShubhamJohri like this? $2^n(n(M+\frac{5M}{2} - \frac{14M}{2})-\frac{5M}{2} + \frac{28M}{4})$

Comment: Yes, although it should be $-14M/4$. Refer to the answer below

Comment: @ShubhamJohri yes, typo. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last line is
$$k^n(Mn + 5Mnk^{-1}-5Mk^{-1} -14Mnk^{-2} + 28Mk^{-2}) = 2^n$$

As before, you have to take $k=2$.

Your equation can therefore be rewritten as
$$
Mn(1+5/2-14/4)-5M/2+28M/4=1.
$$
Since $1+5/2-14/4=0$, you see that the coefficient before $Mn$ is $0$ and there remains $-5M/2+28M/4=1$, hence $M=2/9$.

Comment: Do we use $-\frac{5M}{2}+\frac{28M}{4} = 1$ because we can't use $1+\frac{5}{2} - \frac{14}{4} = 1$ because $0 \ne 1$?

Comment: What do we set $n$ too in the particular solution, $1$?

Comment: Since $1+5/2-14/4=0$, your equation is simply $-5M/2+28M/4=1$ because the term in $n$ vanishes. Then you have to solve this equation in $M$

Comment: You do not have to set $n$ in the particular solution. The particular solution you find is $y_n=(2/9)n2^n$.

Comment: @user644361 $n$ is a variable, it doesn't take a specific value here. For example, your particular solution could be $n2^n$. For the RHS and LHS to be equal, the coefficient of $n$ should be equal. The coefficient of $n$ is zero in the RHS

Answer (score 1):

Using the variation of constants method. Assuming

$$
y_n = A_n(-7)^n+B_n 2^n
$$

after substituting into the difference equation we have

$$
2(-7)^n(7A_n-5A_{n-1}+2A_{n-2})-2^n 7(2B_n+5B_{n-1}-7B_{n-2}-2) = 0
$$

so choosing now

$$
7A_n-5A_{n-1}+2A_{n-2}=0\\
2B_n+5B_{n-1}-7B_{n-2}=2
$$

we have after solving

$$
A_n = C_1\left(-\frac 27\right)^n+C_2\\
B_n = -\frac {1}{81}(2-9n)+\left(-\frac 72\right)^n C_3+C_4
$$

then choosing $C_1=C_2=C_3=C_4=0$ we have finally

$$
A_n = 0\\
B_n = -\frac {1}{81}(2-9n)
$$